# How to set scheduled task in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

How to set scheduled task in dolphindb?

I need to set a scheduled task such as to caculate the new data at 9 o'clock every night. How to make it?

Answer (score 1):

[scheduleJob](https://www.dolphindb.cn/en/help/index.html?scheduleJob.html) can be used to schedule a function or script that performs the processing of data at specified time and with specified frequency.